# JsRender API and printing an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I would like to use JsRender API. The reason for this is the fact that I'm looking for a solution where I have to execute `$("#persons").html(html);` only once.

Anyway, my code does not work at the moment.

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery code with an array:

```
var person_data = [];

person_data[0]["number"] = 1;
person_data[0]["firstName"] = "John";
person_data[0]["lastName"] = "Doe";
person_data[0]["age"] = 46;

person_data[1]["number"] = 2;
person_data[1]["firstName"] = "Ben";
person_data[1]["lastName"] = "Davidson";
person_data[1]["age"] = 25;

var html_code = $("#personTemplate").render(person_data);

$("#persons").html(html_code);
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="persons">
</div>

<script id="personTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <table id="person{{:number}}">
      <tr><td>{{:firstName}}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>{{:lastName}}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>{{:age}}</td></tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

So, I would like the results to be like this:

```
<div id="persons">
  <table id="person1">
    <tr><td>John</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Doe</td></tr>
    <tr><td>46</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table id="person2">
    <tr><td>Ben</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Davidson</td></tr>
    <tr><td>25</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If there are other ways than using JsRender API to do the job without executing `$("#persons").html(html);` more than once, I would like to know more about them.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to initialize the array correctly. Your code will produce a JavaScript error on the line `person_data[0]["number"] = 1;` and not even reach the call to JsRender.

Replace the first line by `var person_data = [{}, {}];` or replace all your array initialization code by:

```
var person_data = [{
  number: 1,
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 46
}, {
  number: 2,
  firstName: "Ben",
  lastName: "Davidson",
  age: 25
}];
```

and everything should work fine with a single call to the following lines:

```
var html_code = $("#personTemplate").render(person_data);

$("#persons").html(html_code);.
```